# Excel VBA Function : Calculate seconds(also counts the milliseconds) from two dates

Tags: vba, excel

This is the follow up post of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38181833/excel-2010-find-seconds-between-two-date-time) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38184238/calculate-seconds-from-two-datetime)

I have created the following VBA function to calculate the seconds(also count the milliseconds) from two datetime.

**Function**:

```
Public Function ConvertDate(D1 As String, D2 As String) As Date
 Dim StrD1 As Date
 Dim StrD2 As Date
  StrD1 = CDate(Left(D1, 10) & " " & Replace(Mid(D1, 12, 8), ".", ":"))
  StrD2 = CDate(Left(D2, 10) & " " & Replace(Mid(D2, 12, 8), ".", ":"))
  ConvertDate = DateDiff("s", StrD2, StrD1)
End Function
```

**Scenario 1**:

Given Dates:

```
 2011-05-13-04.36.14.366004
 2011-05-13-04.36.14.366005
```

**Getting Result**:

```
0
```

**Expected Result**:

```
0.000001
```

**Scenario 2**:

Given Dates:

```
 2011-05-13-04.36.14.366004
 2011-05-13-04.36.15.366005
```

**Getting Result**:

```
1
```

**Expected Result**:

```
1.000001
```

**Scenario 3**:

Given Dates:

```
 2011-05-13-04.36.14.366004
 2011-05-13-04.37.14.366005
```

**Getting Result**:

```
60
```

**Expected Result**:

```
60.000001
```

Comment: Milliseconds (thousandths of a second) are only three decimal places; you want millionths of a second. Use vars of type double, not dates and times.

Comment: @Jeeped, I think that i got stuck while converting value to date and the function which calculate the difference between them.

Comment: [excel] and [excel-vba] can track milliseconds (3 decimal places) but not millionths of a second (6 decimal places). If you want that degree of accuracy then use a floating point double as the variable type.

Comment: @Jeeped, Have tried with `Public Function ConvertDate(D1 As String, D2 As String) As Double
 Dim StrD1 As Double
 Dim StrD2 As Double
  StrD1 = CDate(Left(D1, 10) & " " & Replace(Mid(D1, 12, 8), ".", ":") & "." & Right(D1, 6))
  StrD2 = CDate(Left(D2, 10) & " " & Replace(Mid(D2, 12, 8), ".", ":") & "." & Right(D2, 6))
  ConvertDate = DateDiff("s", StrD2, StrD1)
End Function` but still got nothing out of it.

Comment: Please never put code in comments. They are not designed for that.[Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38199207/edit) your question to include the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A day is **1**. A date is 1 for every day past 31-Dec-1899. Today happens to be 42,556. Time is a decimal portion os a day. Today at noon will be 42,556.5 and today at 06:00 pm will be 42,556.75.

There are 24 hours in a day, 60 minutes in an hour and 60 seconds in a minute. That means that there are 86,400 seconds in a day (24 × 60 × 60) and a second is ¹⁄₈₆₄₀₀ (0.0000115740740740741) of a day. Excel's 15 digit floating point calculation sometimes fouls up (loses small amounts) time calculations due to the base-24 and base-60 numbering system.

```
Dim tm1 As String, tm2 As String
Dim dbl1 As Double, dbl2 As Double
Dim i As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet9")
    For i = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row Step 2
        tm1 = .Cells(i, "A").Text
        tm2 = .Cells(i + 1, "A").Text

        dbl1 = CLng(CDate(Left(tm1, 10))) + _
               TimeValue(Replace(Mid(tm1, 12, 8), Chr(46), Chr(58))) + _
              (CDbl(Mid(tm1, 20)) / 86400)
        dbl2 = CLng(CDate(Left(tm2, 10))) + _
               TimeValue(Replace(Mid(tm2, 12, 8), Chr(46), Chr(58))) + _
              (CDbl(Mid(tm2, 20)) / 86400)
        .Cells(i + 1, "B") = (dbl2 - dbl1) * 86400
        .Cells(i + 1, "B").NumberFormat = "0.000000"
    Next i

End With
```

The above takes your time-and-date-as-text and calculates a pseudo-DateDiff to an accuracy of a millionth of a second. The results are displayed in seconds as an integer with fractions of a second as a decimal.

[image: millionth_seconds]